# Get the index value of a focused but not selected row in a fmMultiSelectSingle ListBox

Tags: excel, vba

I wrote a procedure below so that a row in the `ListBox1` toggles between selected and unselected by pressing the enter key or the space key:

```
Private Sub ListBox1_KeyPress(ByVal KeyAscii As MSForms.ReturnInteger)
    Select Case KeyAscii
        Case 13, 32
        With ListBox1
            If .ListIndex <> -1 Then
                .Selected(.ListIndex) = Not (.Selected(.ListIndex))
            End If
        End With
    End Select
End Sub
```

It works if the `MultiSelect` property is set `fmMultiSelectMulti`, but not for `fmMultiSelectSingle` (i.e. unselectable but not re-selectable). It is because, with a `fmMultiSelectSingle` listbox, `ListIndex` stores -1 once unselected.

If a property (say, "foo") which stores the index of a **focused** row were available, I could change the main part of the above procedure like below:

```
        With ListBox1
            .Selected(.foo) = Not (.Selected(.foo))
        End With
```

(Please note that a "focus" has the same meaning as used in the Microsoft Docs https://learn.microsoft.com/ja-jp/office/vba/language/reference/user-interface-help/listindex-property)

It is likely that such a property exists somewhere because, even with a `fmMultiSelectSingle` listbox,:

- A row just unselected is surrounded by a dotted rectangular.
- By pressing an up/down arrow key, a dotted rectangular moves to the next row.

I cannot explain such behavior without the third property other than `Selected` and `ListIndex`. On the properties list of a listbox shown in the local window of VBIDE at run time I found `ListCursor` property, but could not get any parameter out of it.

Anyone please let me know how I can reach such a property. If it is not available in the scope of VBA, the fact is also helpful.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

User forms are a Class, you can extend them by adding your own private data, Properties or Methods.

Simply add `Private Foo As WhatEverYouWant` at Module scope.  Use it to store the previous value

Comment: What a simple solution! I successfully made it by following your advice using `_BeforeUpdate` event. Many thanks, chris!

Comment: p.s. As I am a novice to SO community, my 'useful' vote is recorded but does not change the display. Sorry about that, chris.